# Tag upvote calculation

Tags: support, tags

Let's say the follow chain of events occur:

- User posts an answer to a question   without tag `foo`.
- User gets some upvotes (let's say 3) to the answer.
- Post gets marked with tag `foo`.
- User gets more upvotes (say 2 more).

For purposes of the tag badge calculation, does the user get 2 points, or 5?

While we're on the topic, if someone downvotes you, do you lose a vote on the tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Five.  When tag badge calculations are run, they use the current vote counts at that time.

Comment: How do you know this?

Comment: With Brock, I don't want to sound skeptical, but I am. ;) Are you able to cite your source on this?

Comment: Nope.  The truth is my only defense.

Answer (score 5):

The amount of votes at the time the badge calculator runs is what counts.

This was tested and verified on Bob's [historic regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) answer some time ago.  Any tag attached to that question gives him that tag's badge.

Tag badges do go away if the count isn't maintained, though, so removing a tag later will cause you to lose the tag if your other answers don't hold enough votes on questions in that tag.

Comment: Verifiable tests are always good. @Benny had pointed me to `data.stackexchange` and the queries there. Is that reliable? Because its results seem shady. Specifically, my electorate progress (which is simply impossible lol), but even my Java tag progress is off by almost 40%, which seems a quite large margin of error between recalcs. I don't have a post with higher than 10 votes in it, so to have that many disappear just seems wrong. How does one go about triggering a recalc of tag votes?

Comment: @glowcoder I don't understand the problem.  I think you may need to post a question specifically about what you think is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think @chaos is right and about the down vote. The down vote would mean -1 vote on that badge. Have a look at https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/137/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-towards-tag-specialist-badges and get someone to down vote you then see if that counts.

Comment: Is it worth noting that my votes according to my user page for the java tag are 200, but according to that query it registers at 127? That's a pretty large discrepancy.

Comment: @glowcoder when did you last do a recalc?

Comment: @benny I triggered a rep recalc the other day, but I didn't know there was a vote recalc. For what it's worth, it says I only have 11 votes for the electorate badge, and that all 11 are on questions (which is simply... well... very wrong...)

Comment: @glowcoder data there gets refreshed monthly (around 15th) to include all the activity for the previous month. That means, only your activity before January 31st counts. Check [faq](http://data.stackexchange.com/faq), **How frequently is Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?**.

Comment: Interesting - thank you for that tidbit, Nikita!

Comment: @Nikita your change to that comment means everything. Is that to mean there is a timeframe the Electorate tag? I.e. it must be 600 votes in 30 days? If so, that's a hidden specification.

Comment: @glowcoder No, monthly update schedule do not affect badge computations, it's related to odata.se.com only. As for electorate badge query, I'm puzzled by it myself, although I did'n attempt to look into it.

Comment: @Nikita thanks! for the record, according to the query, Jon Skeet has 17 - so I guess if I have 11 I'm not doing that bad! ;-)